linux ssd write speed
my computer have a modern cpu with 8 cores and a nvme ssd drive (95% free).
the nvme ssd is connected to the mainboard with pcie 3.
filesystem is ext4 with discard option.
linux kerel is 6.6.38
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
with hdparm is do a read speed test:
hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme1n1p5
/dev/nvme1n1p5:
 Timing cached reads:   44518 MB in  1.99 seconds = 22317.28 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 4764 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1587.79 MB/sec

with dd i do a write speed test too:
dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile1
^C19047808+0 records in
19047808+0 records out
9752477696 bytes (9,8 GB, 9,1 GiB) copied, 11,0414 s, 883 MB/s

if i start more than one dd if=/dev/zero of=testfileN & for writing to the nvme ssd drive, i see in other programms liks htop the write speed is about 1800 mb/s (N = 1 2 3 4 5)
i try the same with random instead zero, the same speed about 1800 mb/s
why?
how to speed up one write to a file with full speed?
are there any special kernel options they i need?

Did you try with the bs for (Block size) option in dd?

https://serverfault.com/questions/650086/does-the-bs-option-in-dd-really-improve-the-speed

If you interrupt dd on write, the speed numbers from it will likely be wrong.  Even if you don't interrupt it, if you don't add a sync, it will still be wrong as the kernel will continue writes in the background in both cases.

Also, SSDs are notorious for having slow write speeds (potentially 4x slower than read) due to write leveling.  It might only be 2x slower if you TRIM the drive.

Do not mount with discard. It slows system & trim will later take care of releasing obsolete data. After installing, change the fstab so that everything gets mounted with noatime. Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware to latest available. Compare to vendors support site
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &  udisksctl status`
